# Looping result from SQL select query

Tags: arrays, go, arraylist

So am learning Go - Language atm 
and I still confused on how do I iterate arraylist that I get from SQL when I execute my query

here is for the detail

I got a file named **CustomerDao.go**
which contains a bunch of queries and the query I uses now is

```
SELECT mst_customer.mcus_mlok_pk , mst_customer.mcus_mlok_kode , mst_customer.mcus_nama FROM frontend.mst_customer;
```

which will return 50 rows of data and 3 columns yes?
now the confusing part is when I reach my controller
which is like this

```
func GetArrayListCustomer(queryType string) (map[string]CustomerModelResponse, error) {
    logger := customlogger.GetInstance()
    logger.Println("Service: GetArrayListCustomer Start")

    queryText := dao.CustomerDAO(queryType)
    res, err := config.GetDbByPath("myDatabase").GetDb().Query(queryText)

    mapList := make(map[string]CustomerModelResponse)
    var custResponse CustomerModelResponse

    if config.FancyHandleError(err) {
        logger.Println("Service: GetArrayListCustomer -> Error " + err.Error())
        return mapList, err
    }
    defer res.Close()
    for res.Next() {
        errs := res.Scan(&custResponse.McusmlokPk, &custResponse.McusmlokKode, &custResponse.McusNama)
        for _, eachCust := range res {
            //the error goes here , for some reason
        }
    }
    return mapList, nil
}
```

and then I try to loop the value then the error show that I cannot range over res which is a *sql.Rows how do I declare those result as an array not as a *sql.Rows type?

Comment: You're already looping over the the rows with `for res.Next() {` and `res.Scan`, you don't need that inner `range res` loop.

Comment: something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/0haTTOrqLjC

Comment: note that you need to do `var custResponse CustomerModelResponse` inside the loop, not outside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scan your values into a struct, using `rows.Next` you loop over the sql results your query gives, you need to scan those results (on each loop) into your desired struct, and save that struct into something (a map in this case)

```
func GetArrayListCustomer(queryType string) (map[string]CustomerModelResponse, error) {
    logger := customlogger.GetInstance()
    logger.Println("Service: GetArrayListCustomer Start")

    queryText := dao.CustomerDAO(queryType)
    res, err := config.GetDbByPath("myDatabase").GetDb().Query(queryText)

    mapList := make(map[string]CustomerModelResponse)

    if config.FancyHandleError(err) {
        logger.Println("Service: GetArrayListCustomer -> Error " + err.Error())
        return mapList, err
    }
    defer res.Close()
    for res.Next() {
        var custResponse CustomerModelResponse
        if err := res.Scan(&custResponse.McusmlokPk, &custResponse.McusmlokKode, &custResponse.McusNama); err != nil {
            // Handle error
        }
        mapList[cutResponse.McusmlokPk] = custResponse
    }
    // Now mapList is a map with McusmlokPk as key and CustomerModelResponse struct as value
    return mapList, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks it just get me confused that I just know the .next() function is same as for loop in java , that's why I got error when I try to loop my res object

Answer (score 2):

You can not use `for range` loop on `res`. `res` can only be iterated using `Next()`. Following is what you can do:

```
for res.Next() {

    //CREATE A NEW ZERO VALUE CustomerModelResponse FOR EACH ITERATION
    var custResponse CustomerModelResponse

    // UPDATE CustomerModelResponse WITH ROW DATA
    errs := res.Scan(&custResponse.McusmlokPk, &custResponse.McusmlokKode, &custResponse.McusNama)

    if errs == nil {
        // APPEND THE NEWLY CREATED & UPDATED CustomerModelResponse TO mapList
        // ASSUMINg mst_customer.mcus_mlok_pk AS KEY FOR THE MAP

        mapList[custResponse.McusmlokPk] = custResponse
    }

    /*
        THIS LOOP IS NOT NEEDED ANY MORE

        for _, eachCust := range res {
            //the error goes here , for some reason
        }
    */
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it just get me confused that I just know the .next() function is same as for loop in java , that's why I got error when I try to loop my res object